# Access Each Class Element In C#

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, xamarin.forms, foreach

I am creating an application using Xamarin.Forms. I am trying to access each element in the list of MovieRent instances. I have a class that stores movie information:

```
 public class MovieRent
    {
        public string movieTitle { get; set; }
        public string movieReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public int movieDuration { get; set; }
        public double movieRentalPrice { get; set; }
        public string movieRentType { get; set; }

        public MovieRent(string mtitle, string mdate, int mtime, double mprice, string type)
        {
            movieTitle = mtitle;
            movieReleaseDate = mdate;
            movieDuration = mtime;
            movieRentalPrice = mprice;
            movieRentType = type;
        }
    }
```

addCartList is called to add a movie to a list. This creates/stores a list of movies.

```
 class MoviesToRent
    {
        public List<MovieRent> movieRentList;
        public MoviesToRent()
        {
            movieRentList = new List<MovieRent>();
        }

        public static MoviesToRent addCartList(string title, string date, int duration, double price, string type)
        {
            MoviesToRent movieList = new MoviesToRent();

            MovieRentnewMovie = new MovieRent(title, date, duration, price, type);

            movieList.movieRentList.Add(newMovie);

            return movieList;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to access each instance, for example, the title of each movie in the list:

```
foreach (string movie in MoviesToRent.movieRentList) 
{
   this.Movie_Info.Text = movieRentList.title;
}
```

However, I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'MoviesToRent.movieRentList'.

How can I overcome this error, so that I can access the movies that are in the list? I am trying display all movie info by looping through the list.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to access movieRentList as a static property. You need a instance of MoviesToRent and then access the list.

```
var movieRents = new MoviesToRent();
for (var movieRent in movieRents.movieRentList) 
{

}
```

PS: In the example above, the list will be empty because I didnt add any object to it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I first have to fix that naming and some glaring code issues. It is confusing the heck out of me:

```
 public class Movie
    {
        public string movieTitle { get; set; }
        public string movieReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public int movieDuration { get; set; }
        public double movieRentalPrice { get; set; }
        public string movieRentType { get; set; }

        public MovieRent(string mtitle, string mdate, int mtime, double mprice, string type)
        {
            movieTitle = mtitle;
            movieReleaseDate = mdate;
            movieDuration = mtime;
            movieRentalPrice = mprice;
            movieRentType = type;
        }
    }


class MoviesRentCart
    {
        public List<Movie> movieRentList;
        public MoviesToRent()
        {
            movieRentList = new List<MovieRent>();
        }

        public static MoviesToRent addCartList(string title, string date, int duration, double price, string type)
        {
            //What does this line do here?
            //MoviesToRent movieList = new MoviesToRent();

            //fixed missing space
            Movie newMovie = new Movie(title, date, duration, price, type);

            movieList.movieRentList.Add(newMovie);

            return movieList;
        }
    }
```

Then in your actuall code, you need a instance of MovieRentCart. Same way you make an instance of Movie. To that *instance*, you add the elements. Over that *instance*'s movieRentList, you itterate.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you're trying to access `movieRentList` as if it where a static field member of the class `MoviesToRent`. You need an instance of `MoviesToRent` like so:

```
var moviesToRent = new MoviesToRent();
```

And to access the title of each movie in the list do:

```
foreach (MovieRent movie in moviesToRent.movieRentList)
{
   //The movie title is movie.movieTitle
}
```